# Trying to Insert a Variable into MSSQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I am attempting to insert some variables into MSSQL and its giving me a 500 server error

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

However it works when I substitute simple number or text values for those variables.   I am running Wamp server and connecting to an amazon RDS MSSSQL instance.  Here is my code:

```
$status = "closed";

$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);

$query = "INSERT INTO DatabaseTableName (ColumnName) VALUES ('$status')";

$results = odbc_exec($connection, $query);
if ($results){
    echo "Query Executed";
}else {
    echo "Query failed " .odbc_error();
}
```

It works if I remove the variable `$status` and put in a number or a word instead.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, what is the run-time value of $status? Can you log the value of $query after you declare it to see if it is what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO DatabaseTableName (ColumnName) VALUES ('".$status."')";
```

You may want to look into cleansing your input as well.

See [mysqli real escape string](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

Comment: That does actually work, thank you! However only when the value of $status is a number, when i change it to a word, it does not work.  However I cant see  the error, that its throwing back. It gives me a 500 error or if I comment out the line that says: "echo "Query failed " .odbc_error();" then I get a blank screen but it doesnt write to my database.  Any ideas?

Comment: I did a quick google search for odbc internal server error and it gave me a few hits.  I am not familiar with odbc, so i am not sure why it is giving you that error.  You may want to make sure that you are (at least) escaping your input to make sure that you are executing a valid query.  For example: if $status equaled test's then your query would read VALUES ('test's').  See how that could be a problem?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what it would look like for more than one column to be filled with variables?   Words are still not working and those columns are varchar columns

Comment: Nevermind, it goes like this and its working:
=======
    $query = "INSERT INTO TableName (columnone, column2) VALUES    ('".$status."' , '".$status2."')";
======